# createTreeWalker in IE - is there a limit?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there any static limit to the amount of nodes a createTreeWalker can accept in IE 10-11? Recently i been building a application who runs through a series of nodes to figure out which ones are shown & which ones aint. I'm thinking the problem might be the amount of nodes that I'm having. Due to that it is a formatted book I'm showing, there could be 50.000 nodes atleast.

My current Walker code that is causing the issue is:

```
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
    element,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    {
        acceptNode: function(nodeItem) {
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }
    },
    false
);

var node;

while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
    visibleElements.push(node);
}
```

[image]

Can't seem to find any documentation claiming that there might be a static limit to how many nodes a walker can handle in IE. But what you see in the error message is all i got. The error exception points to the very lime containing "while(..."

Anyone else had this issue happen to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - after some intense debugging i figured out that through the MSDN documentation the parameter that on every other browser is a object specifying a **acceptNode**. Is instead specified as a function. It's not wrapped in a object with the index **acceptNode**

IE. For the love of god. Get us some informative exceptions :)